# For-loop fails replacing -1

Tags: r

I have a problem using a for-loop in R. The following code

```
a <- seq(-2, 5)
for(i in 1:length(a)){
  a[i] <- if(a[i] <= 0) "aa" else a[i]
}
```

should result in the following vector

```
> a
[1] "aa" "aa" "aa" "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"
```

Instead we have the following result:

```
> a
[1] "aa" "-1" "aa" "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"
```

Why isn't R able to replace "-1" with "aa"?

We tried another solution which works fine:

```
a <- seq(-2, 5)
b <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(a)){
  b[i] <- if(a[i] <= 0) "aa" else a[i]
}
```

it produces the expected result:

```
> b
[1] "aa" "aa" "aa" "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"
```

Why does the latter example work fine and the first one not?

Thank you very much for your help!

Best regards!!

Comment: Unable to reproduce. You're making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: A side note: although your loop seems to work just fine, you may want to have a look at `ifelse`. E.g. `ifelse(a <= 0, "aa", a)`

Comment: @MatthewPlourde: The majority is not always correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The collation sequence may not be as you (or Matthew) understand. The character "-" may not be lower in the lexical ordering for your operating system. String comparisons are OS specific. (See `?Comparison`) After the first replacement the entire vector was coerced to character and if `"-" > 0` returns TRUE on your machine then you have the answer. I will bet that this code will act as you expected:

```
a <- seq(-2, 5)
for(i in 1:length(a)){
  a[i] <- if( as.numeric(a[i]) <= 0) "aa" else a[i]
}
```

I suspect that Henrik's suggestion should also behave to your expectations because it would create a logical vector from the numeric comparison first, and then select from the choice of "aa" and `a`.

(In the second instance there was no coercion of the vector to character.)